Is not a CMS a way to call a system all web developments must have?
I am lost.
I know whats a CMS, I know there is multiples solutions (mainly on php and js).
Now, I have build some SpringBoot webapps using Angular or Thymeleaf doesnt matter for this question.
Well, when i was developing my Springboot app obviously the admin user can access to an specific view (or CMS or Admin view) where the this admin (or owner of the app) can manage their contents, users, publishing posts, etc. Is this a CMS? Whats the difference between this and already builded CMS.
Its not the admin view (as i called here), the properly CMS?
If not, whats the benefits to use an external CMS framework. For example, on my apps i implement the BBDD, the restAPI service layer on Springboot and then the front with Angular, where it fits an external CMS as Strapi.
I do not know if I am explaining my self. If you have some question or you thing I mistake on the questions please tell me. I know it may be I am lost so I would appreciate your help.
Thank you.
To resume:
¿It a CMS the way they call the admin system manager on the app?
¿If I decided to use an external CMS, where it fits? Just develop front-end, and then use Strapi (for example) as a backend?
I have try to search information about it. But I only found explanations of What is a CMS? Or How to implements a CMS on Springboot? but no one have think about this question.
